# How can I use a passive form of a gerund to replace the bold words?

Tags: gerunds

During studying the book of "Top Notch", I come across the below sentence. Who can help me use a passive form of a gerund to replace the bold words?

> We can't tolerate **their calling us** While we are eating dinner.

Comment: "We can't tolerate being called by them ... " is reasonably close.

Comment: Why?  Generally when I am reading a book, I don't want to change the words.

Comment: @JamesK it is obvious because it seems you are a native English speaker, and nor! do I. I wanna learn, thinking it is a kina a clause reduction. Could you tell me why the bolded expression doesn't have the subject and "to be" verb before "calling" also the role of "their"? That expression is to what extent uncanny to me.

Comment: In your example "their calling us" is a clause with "their" as subject and "calling us" as predicate. Incidentally, you'll never learn English if you use slang words like "wanna" and "kinda".

Comment: @Alan but I don't think this is a productive way of learning.  In particular, you need to learn when to use a passive and when not to.  The author here uses an active voice.  Why is that?  Sure, its possible to transform most transitive verb phrases into a passive voice, but don't do that; you're not practicing English. Instead read for interest, comprehension and vocabulary building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was two separate sentences:

> 1-     **They call us** While we are eating dinner.
> 2- We can't tolerate **it**.

After the combination of the two sentences, you have:

> We can't tolerate **their calling us** while we are eating dinner.

Now for using a passive form of a gerund to replace with the bold words, you can have:

> We can't tolerate **being called by them** while we are eating dinner.